# On probability of coprimality of a list of numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, pr.probability, analytic-number-theory, probabilistic-number-theory

We know $r$ randomly chosen integers are coprime with probability $\frac1{\zeta(r)}$.

Pick a bound $N$ and pick $k\lceil N^{\alpha}\rceil$ uniformly random integers in $[0,N^{\alpha+\beta}]$ where $\alpha,\beta,\alpha+\beta\in(0,1)$. Call the integers $$a_{11},\dots,a_{1\lceil N^{\alpha}\rceil}$$
$$a_{21},\dots,a_{2\lceil N^{\alpha}\rceil}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$a_{k1},\dots,a_{k\lceil N^{\alpha}\rceil}.$$

Set for every $i\in\{1,\dots,k\}$, $$b_i=\prod_{j=1}^{\lceil N^{\alpha}\rceil}a_{ij}.$$ Assume $k=\Omega(\ln\ln N)$.

> 1. What is the probability the integers $b_1,\dots,b_k$ have $$\mathsf{GCD}(b_1,\dots,b_k)=1$$ for large $N$? Is it close to $\frac{1}{\zeta(k)^{\lceil N^{\alpha}\rceil^{k}}}$ or something else (may be just $\frac1{\zeta(k)}$)?

> 2. What is the probability the integers $b_1,\dots,b_k$ have $$\mathsf{GCD}(b_1,\dots,b_k)<N^\gamma$$ for large $N$ at a $\gamma\in(0,\alpha+\beta)$?

I am looking for good enough lower and upper bounds.